# Memory leak when reading a file in Java

Tags: java, json, garbage-collection, fileinputstream

I have a 54,120 byte JSON file which is all on one line

I'm trying to read this into a String in an Android application using:

```
//Method from class FileManager
public String readInternalFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),"Reading Internal File: " + filename);

        // Open file
        FileInputStream fIS = context.openFileInput(filename);
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),"File is " + fIS.available() + " bytes");

        // Process file
        String s = "";
        int ch;
        while ((ch = fIS.read()) != -1) {
            s += (char) ch;
        }

        //Close InputStream
        if(fIS!= null){
            fIS.close();
        }
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),"File is " + s.length() + " characters long");
        return s;
}
```

When I run this in my JUnit test application or in an Emulator I get a wall of Log text for the garbage collector:

[image: Log data]

This never seems to end and is slowing down my application. Is there a way I can read this in that wouldn't cause this?

If it helps the JSON file can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuzrmf2hgkao4kh/page_list_test). It's just a news Feed.

Comment: I think the problem is with the way you're building up your `String`... Don't use concatenation. Use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but there must be better ways to read a file than by doing it one character at a time.

Comment: You should newer use += with a string. Use a StringBuffer instead and call append on it to add each char. Also wrap your input stream in a BufferedInputStream

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My thoughts exactly, I'll investigate StringBuilder

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have tried using a BufferedReader with readLine() appending to a StringBuilder and still have the same problem with the Garbage Collector

Comment: I don't understand why but one way to avoid this was to format the JSON file before it is read to a "pretty print" style with new lines and indents and then read line by line

Comment: This doesn't look like a memory leak, but was instead the garbage collector doing frequent garbage collection. The reason for this was the reading of a string char by char. For each char you read, java converts the char to a String (so that's one new object), then you concatenate and assign it to `s`, that's another new object. So that's at least 108240 new objects for your 54120 byte file that have a very short lifespan before the garbage collector tries to clean them up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to format the `JSON` file before it is read to a "*pretty print*" style with new lines and indents and then use a `BufferedReader` with `readLine()`